# How to make MongoDB available inside Express' HTTP methods?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to use MongoDB with Node/Express. I made the [official example](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/client/) work:

```
var express = require('express')
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var assert = require('assert')
var app = express()

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject'
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err)
  console.log("Connected correctly to server")

  insertDocuments(db, function() {
    db.close()
  })
})

var insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  var collection = db.collection('documents')
  // Insert some documents
  collection.insertMany([
    // Some code
  ], function(err, result) {
    // Some code
    callback(result)
  })
}

app.get('/insert-document', function(req, res) {
  // res.send()
})
```

How can I make it so that Mongo is available inside Express' HTTP methods? For instance, to use `insertDocuments()` inside `app.get('/insert-document', function(req, res)`?

**EDIT (full `server.js` file):**

```
var express = require('express')
// var PouchDB = require('pouchdb')
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var assert = require('assert')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('./webpack.dev.conf')

var app = express()
var compiler = webpack(config)

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject'
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
var db

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err)
  console.log("Connected correctly to server")
  db = db
})

var insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  var collection = db.collection('documents')
  // Insert some documents
  collection.insertMany([
    {a : 1}, {a : 2}, {a : 3}
  ], function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null)
    assert.equal(3, result.result.n)
    assert.equal(3, result.ops.length)
    console.log("Inserted 3 documents into the document collection")
    callback(result)
  })
}

// handle fallback for HTML5 history API
app.use(require('connect-history-api-fallback')())

// serve webpack bundle output
app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    chunks: false
  }
}))

// enable hot-reload and state-preserving
// compilation error display
app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler))

app.get('/docs', function(req, res) {
  // res.send()
  insertDocuments(db, function() {
    db.close()
  })
})

app.listen(8080, 'localhost', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return
  }
  console.log('Listening at http://localhost:8080')
})
```

I get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
>       at insertDocuments (/home/alex/node/project-mongo/build/dev-server.js:24:22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer codes [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html), save the connection `db` as one global variable, sample codes as below.

```
var db;

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      assert.equal(null, err)
      console.log("Connected correctly to server")

      db = db;
      // Start the application after the database connection is ready
      app.listen(3000);
      console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

// Reuse database object in request handlers
app.get('/insert-document', function(req, res) {
      // insertDocuments() could invoked here.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`. Please see my **EDIT**. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @alex, please put the function `app.listen(8080, 'localhost',` into `mongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){})` as shown in my answer...

Comment: I did this: `MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err)
  console.log("Connected correctly to server")
  db = db
  
  app.listen(8080, 'localhost', function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      return
    }
    console.log('Listening at http://localhost:8080')
  })
})` Same error.

Comment: I realized that `db` is undefined inside `app.get('/docs', function(req, res)`.

Comment: Hey it worked. I did `db = database` instead. I think `db = db` was reasigning db to nothing. Thanks for the help.